# How are you supposed to work with enamelled wire?

Tags: soldering

I'm trying to work with Enammelled copper wire such as below, used for winding transformers due to its insulation. How on earth do you work with this type of wire?

When cutting the wire, the internal exposed copper surface is so small it makes a very weak connection. Am I supposed to blast the Enamel with heat and melt it away? Are there any common practices when working with this type of wire?

[image]

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I'm not asking how to remove the enamel. I'm asking common practices for working with this wire. In mass production wire winding facilities, I'm sure they are not sanding off enamel when making transformers.

Comment: Then state it clearly in the question.

Comment: There are chemical strippers e.g. E-Sol

Comment: I always just scraped off the enamel with a knife edge.

Comment: I usually just burn thru with solder.

Comment: A knife edge can work, though it does often cause lots of gouges in the metal which could cause undue stress. Another method is using sand paper folded in half around the wire, then squeeze and pull a few times until the enamel is gone.

Comment: The comments are repeating the answers in the proposed duplicate, while the OP is claiming that it is not the question.

Comment: If you want to learn about industrial magnet-wire stripping techniques, tools and machines, search using those terms. Non-industrial techniques are adequately covered in answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping someone had experience in this field rather than the hobbyist ideas. EE.stack is mainly students so perhaps a stretch. There are many machines such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wo9g2dx34o I guess are likely used in industrial applications. I'll pick on up and see how I get on.

Comment: By the way, if you attempt to scrape with a knife you are likley to snap 0.1mm wire, and if you burn it the enamal turns into a burnt paste. Sand-papering I very highly doubt is common practice due to the manual labor involved and required clean-up.

Comment: Dip the end of the wire in the solder pot. This will burn away the enamel and leave a tinned surface that is easy to solder. This is how it's most often done in the industry. In order to "work with this wire" as you ask in your question, you need to remove the enamel. Therefore, the question boils down to the same issue discussed in the duplicate post: How to remove the enamel to make the wire easy to work with.